# How to make a horizontally scrollable TableLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a scrollable view / layout with a constraint layout in it.

Inside of this layout I have a lot of other stuff. On the bottom of the layout I need a Tablelayout which I create programatically.

How can I make this TableLayout scrollable horizontally?

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/testlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutProductTableHeader">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProductTable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

I tried to use a HorizontalLayout inside the ScrollView too but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it and works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/layout" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"         
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"     
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"     
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:fillViewport="true"> 
  <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
           <TableLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tlGridTable" >   
           </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think the problem is because I add the table rows and columns programatically.